# Install USB/IP on Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 22.04

Attempting to install USB/IP on Ubuntu 22.04 per the [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb#install-the-usbip-tools-and-hardware-database-in-linux):

> On Ubuntu, run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic hwdata
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/usbip usbip /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic/usbip 20
> ```

But running that results in:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic'
```

How do I install USB/IP on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL?

Comment: You need to run `sudo upgrade` after `sudo update-alternatives`.

Comment: @BugHunterUK You might be thinking `sudo ` ***`apt`*** `update` and `upgrade`?  That's vastly different than `sudo update-alternatives`.  There's no reason to run either `sudo upgrade` or `sudo apt upgrade` after a `sudo update-alternatives`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While my original answer should still work, I've updated it with a slightly more optimal version based on the directions on the [usbipd-win Wiki](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win/wiki/WSL-support#usbip-client-tools).  Note that these instructions should also work under Ubuntu 20.04, as well as most Debian-lineage distributions:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-virtual hwdata
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/usbip usbip $(command -v ls /usr/lib/linux-tools/*/usbip | tail -n1) 20
```

This will install the `usbip` client from the latest *Ubuntu* kernel package.  This client (`/usr/lib/linux-tools-<x.xx.xx-x>/usbip`) *is* compatible with the WSL2 kernel, but the `linux-tools-common` package includes a stub (`/usr/bin/usbip`) that tries to find the tools in a directory corresponding to the installed kernel.

Keep in mind that, no matter what, your WSL2 kernel is not going to match any kernel version in the Ubuntu repositories.  For this reason, you'll need to create a symlink (via `update-alternatives`) with a higher priority than the `linux-tools-common` package's `/usr/bin/usbip`.

Comment: But WSL kernels are (curently) 5.15.79.1-midrosoft-standard-WSL2, with no matching linux-tools-5.15.79... Kernels run by WSL are not in /boot, did you install a standard kernel in the WSL to make this work?

Comment: @ubfan1 Sorry for the delay responding - Took me a few days to get some time to recheck this.  I just tried on a fresh 22.04 install with WSL2 kernel `5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`, and it's still working for me -- Did you run the second command (`update-alternatives`) to create the symlink?  That's really the key -- Otherwise the generic `/usr/bin/usbip` will get called, which will look for a matching kernel release (which will pretty much never exist on WSL2).  What's `which usbip` show for you?

Comment: @ubfan1 Even so, I'm going to update the answer with a "more optimal" solution.  It still will require the `update-alternatives`, though.

Comment: After getting my USB visible to a  kvm Windows machine, I just use a Windows Desktop directory (dircp) to 1)copy off the USB and 2)make available to WSL at /mnt/c/Users/<User>/Desktop/cpdir .  Never needed much more than that.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3, when I types in the first sudo command line the response was: 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

Comment: @SPlatten Try a `sudo apt update` - It sounds like you might have a stale package cache.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the issue where linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic wasn't found. I ran the following and then it was available.

sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

These tools need to match your systems kernel version. You can see your current version by running `uname -r`. The Microsoft docs link in the question alludes to this in the Prerequisites note by saying that you need to run `uname -a`, which shows multiple pieces of system information, to find your kernel version.

On regular Linux systems you can run this command to automatically read the current kernel version and install the appropriate version of linux-tools.

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-$(uname -r) hwdata
```

This doesn't work on Windows Subsystem for Linux because the kernel version name is non-standard (e.g. 5.15.0-56-microsoft-standard-WSL2).

The `linux-tools-generic` package is linked to the latest kernel version. If you're not looking for a package matching a specific kernel version you can just install that package. I haven't tested yet whether a kernel update will cause the `linux-tools-generic` package to update to the latest version.

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-generic hwdata
```

Just today my WSL kernel updated to 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 but the latest available package in Ubuntu is still linux-tools-5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2. I'll probably try building the tools from source next to be able to try out USB/IP under WSL.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would ever work under WSL2, since the kernel name is never going to match a "stock" Ubuntu kernel in the repositories.  The WSL2 kernel name (`uname -r`) is currently `5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`, which results in `Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2` when I run your suggestion under Ubuntu 22.04.  Can you elaborate on your solution for WSL2 kernels?  Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. I was running this under a native Ubuntu install. When I tried to check this out under my WSL I found exactly what you've said. Under native Ubuntu the `uname -r` version matches the linux-tools package suffix but Microsoft doesn't even seem to have matched the naming convention closely enough to just append `-microsoft-standard-WSL2`.

Comment: Right!  Thanks for confirming and updating.  On the naming/numbering topic, that's true -- The Microsoft kernel version won't necessarily match up with an Ubuntu kernel since they are typically picking different releases to build.  The WSL2 kernel is being used in *many* possible distributions, so even if MS matched it to Ubuntu releases, it would still be "wrong" in other distributions.